# Getting asp:panel elements

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I have a panel called "sp" in a ascx named "sample.ascx".

```
<asp:Panel ID="sp"  runat="server" >
</asp:Panel>
```

My "sample.ascx.cs" file adds components like "Label" and "Textbox" to this panel dynamically.I would like to get the values of all the components in the javascript of the "sample.ascx". 
Please Help!

Comment: you can try `var sp = document.getElementById('<%: sp.ClientID %>');` and then use [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children)

Answer (score 0):

Set the ClientIDMode="Static" for the Server controls u need to access easily using its id itself from the JS.
then try 
var res= $('#sp');
var val1=res.find('#textbox1').val();